# After xslt transformation why file is generated in Tomcat/bin folder ? How can i change this directory to webapps/myApp?

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, xslt, servlets

I have a Java serlvet calling an XSLT file.

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getParameter(
        "content").getBytes("UTF-8"));
    try {
        TransformerFactory tFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(
            getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("lib/GenerateGeddyJsCode.xsl")));
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(inputStream), new StreamResult(
            new FileOutputStream(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
                + "output.txt")));
        System.out.println("======================= The output is in "
            + getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "output.txt."
            + "=======================");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The file `output.txt` is generated by the servlet in `Tomcat/webapps/myApp`, which is ok.

But I actually don't want to generate only one output file. So, inside the XSLT file I try to create multiple output files using `<xsl:result-document>`. For each ObjectType I want to create a different model class (I use the MVC paradigm).

```
<xsl:template match="ObjectType">
  <xsl:result-document href="{@name}.js" format="js">
    <xsl:text>TEXT</xsl:text>
  </xsl:result-document>    
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that the files generated by the XSLT are found in `Tomcat/bin`. Why is this happening? And how can I generate them inside `webapps/myApp`?

Comment: because that where user.dir is pointing.

Comment: and how can I change that?

Comment: Don't use user.dir. Pass in the pathname you want.

Comment: I'm not using it... that's why I deleted those lines... Iwas just printingd the current path to see which is it.

Comment: I want a path relative to the root of the app. I can do that with the servlet, but not from the XSLT file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the path you want with `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` so you could define a global parameter

```
<xsl:param name="dir"/>
```

in your XSLT, use that as in

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$dir}/{@name}.js" format="js">
```

and then set

```
transformer.setParameter("dir", new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")).toURI().toString());
```

before running the transformation.